# How to clean up Ubuntu 22.04 active services that are not needed when used as a virtual machine and only for light predominantly non-GUI usage?

Tags: ram, cpu, services, evolution, memory-usage

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 in a relatively light fashion. My use case is in a virtual machine that runs all of the time, but very occasionally I need to use the graphical user interface. I did this on macOS+Parallels by [installing Ubuntu 22.04 Server and then the Desktop packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405124/install-ubuntu-desktop-22-04-arm64-on-macos-apple-silicon-m1-pro-max-in-parall).

I then modified the system to not start the GUI up automatically so that it's only available on demmand:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
$ sudo reboot
...
# login and then:
$ startx
```

At this point I have found that there are still several services starting that I don't want/need.

How can I disable services such as these with Ubuntu 22.04 (the methodology seems to have changed since previous instructions):

- `evolution-*` (eg, `evolution-calendar-factory`, `evolution-addressbook-factory`, `evolution-source-registry`)
- `goa-daemon`
- `packagekitd` (I'd like to run updates manually.)
- And any others that may be unnecessary for such a usecase scenario...

I did already manage to disable a couple daemons:

- `avahi-daemon` (Stayed at 100% CPU usage / very problematic; `sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon; sudo apt remove avahi-daemon`)
- CUPS (`sudo systemctl stop cups; systemctl stop cups-browsed; sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed; sudo systemctl disable cups; sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed`)

If it's not clear, my intentions are to make Ubuntu as light as possible on CPU and memory usage, while still retaining core functionality to be able to use it for testing and developing some graphical applications from time to time that require Linux + X*.