# Where can I get Ubuntu 20.4 LTS download linkfor Macbook m1?

Tags: 20.04, downloads, macbook

I want to download Ubuntu 20.4 LTS for my M1.

Comment: Have you looked at `https://ubuntu.com/download` ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no downloadable installer to install Ubuntu on Apple silicon. Here is an article that talks about how to install 22.04 on an M1 laptop using Parrellels virtualization software. UTM is another virtualization technology that is free to use that could be made to work.

[Install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 ARM64 on macOS Apple Silicon (M1/Pro/Max) in Parallels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405124/install-ubuntu-desktop-22-04-arm64-on-macos-apple-silicon-m1-pro-max-in-parall)